# Pointers to templated class

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

I am trying to define a graph, where the vertex class is defined with a template. How do I then define a pointer to this templated vertex in another class.

```
template<class T1, class T2>
class Vertex {
public:
  virtual T1 run(T2) = 0;
};


class Graph {
  std::map<std::string, Vertex*> vertices; // <--- How do I do something like this
  int** adjacency_matrix;
public:
  void run() {
     ...
  }
};
```

I have been looking at some other questions on Stack-Overflow, the common suggestion seems to be to use a base class that is not templated, and use the pointers for that and putting the common functions in that class.
However, in my code, the function `run()` which is the common one and uses the template for the return type. So I do not understand how to use the base class.

Any ideas?

Comment: If the function `Vertex::run` uses the template arguments and you want to store pointers to `Vertex` without the template arguments, how are you going to call `Vertex::run`? What are you going to pass to it?

Comment: Thats kind of the problem I have. Do you have any suggestions to get around that?.

Comment: C++ is statically typed so it needs to know the type at compile-time. That means that it needs to know what `T2` is if you are to call `run(T2)`. You can declare multiple maps within `Graph`, one for each combination of `Vertex`'s template arguments you use but that doesn't sound very nice. You might have to review your design and see if there is another way of solving your problem. What are you trying to achieve? You could ask another question which is more aimed at that.

Comment: How do you intend to interact with the `Vertex`s once they are in the `Graph` without knowing their type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as I said, you need a non-template base class from which `Vertex` inherits:

```c++
struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

template<class T1, class T2>
class Vertex : public Base
{
public:
    virtual T1 run(T2) = 0;
};
```

Then inside your `Graph` function you use `std::shared_ptr<Base>` instead of `Vertex*`:

```c++
class Graph {
    std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Base>> vertices;
public:
    void run();
};
```

Now when calling `run()` on the `Vertex` pointer, you need to `dynamic_cast` the pointer back the appropriate derived class. In your case you can't actually call `run()` on a `Vertex*` since `Vertex::run()` is a pure virtual function.

```c++
int main()
{
    Graph g;
    g.vertices["xyz"] = std::make_shared<Vertex<int, int>>();
    // error: field type 'Vertex<int, int>' is an abstract class
}
```

If you want to call `Vertex`, either make `run()` a non pure-virtual function and give it an implementation, or use a derived class for the implementation:

```c++
class Derived : public Vertex<int, int>
{
public:
    int run(int n) { std::cout << n << '\n'; return 0; }
};

class Graph {
    std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Base>> vertices;
public:
    template<class T2>
    void call_run(std::shared_ptr<Base> p, T2 value)
    {
        if (auto derived = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived>(p))
            derived->run(value);

        if (/* other derived classes... */);
    }

    void run();
};
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no class named `Vertex`, only a template for classes.

The simple way out is using polymorphism, as you only store pointers anyway:

Define a base-class all `Vertex` instances (specialized or not) inherit from.

```
template<class T1, class T2>
class Vertex : VertexBase {
public:
  virtual T1 run(T2) = 0;
};

struct VertexBase {
  ~VertexBase() = default;
  template<class T1, class T2> T1 run(T2 x) {
    return dynamic_cast<Vertex<T1,T2>&>(*this).run(x);
  }
};
```

Anyway, also take a look at `std::function` and see whether that solves your problem well enough.

Comment: The problem with the base class is that I need to use the `run()` function, and that uses the template. How do I define this in the base class?

Comment: Added an example, using a template in the base-class for calling `run`.

Answer (score 1):

You can either specify a type like this:

```
std::map<std::string, Vertex<int, int>*> vertices;
```

Or make `Graph` templated as well:

```
template<class T1, class T2>
class Graph {
    std::map<std::string, Vertex<T1, T2>*> vertices;
```

Comment: The thing is that map can have different template implementations of the `Vertex` class. For example one entry might be `Vertex<int, int>` another might be `Vertex<double, long>` and so on

Comment: @subzero You can use my second suggestion.

Comment: But when I instantiate an object of Graph in that case, I would be stuck with only one type of Vertex objects.

Comment: Nope, you can do `Graph<double, long>`.

Comment: What I mean is that if I instantiate say `Graph<int, int> x`. Then I cant do `x.vertices['xyz'] = 1.12121`.

Comment: @subzero Create a base class from which `Vertices` inherits. Now replace `Vertices*` in the map with `Base*` (or whatever name you choose). Then you can dynamically allocate the template class with the parameters you want. But also it's advised to use smart pointers like `std::shared_ptr` to do the memory management for you. :)

Comment: @0x499602D2 But how do I define the `run()` function in `Base` (which uses a template)? I cant access the `run()` function from a `Base*`.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode When you run the code in this answer and call `run()`, that's the error you get.